# Python - while loop ends after 1 request

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have an API endpoint im calling, if i have the two functions grouped together like this it works and continues with the while loop, but if i break it up into functions it only calls it once and stops..., should be farely easy to fix, but why does it only call it 1 time and end?

```
from os import times
from textwrap import indent
from unittest import TestSuite
from urllib import request
from xxlimited import new
import requests
import ssl
import json
import csv
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
import urllib3


def create_spirion_session():

    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

    url = 'https://SV03TMCSPAPP/WebApi/Services/Home/LogOn'
    url2 = 'https://SV03TMCSPAPP/WebApi/Services/Data/LoadEndpoints'

    headers = {
            'Accept':'application/json, text/plain',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }

    has_next_date = True
    timestampfromSpirion = "timestamp_records.csv"
    results = []
    results2 = []
    f = open('spirion.json')
    timestampData = json.load(f)

    with requests.Session() as s:

        ##authenticate first...###
        resp = s.post(url, json={"user": "","password": ""}, headers=headers, verify=False)
        print(resp.status_code)
        
        timestamp = ""
        deleteData = ""
        fields = ""

        while True:

            resp2 = s.post(url2, json={"deleteData": deleteData, "timestamp": timestamp, "fields": fields}, headers=headers, verify=False)
            resp3 = resp2.text.split('\n', 1)[1]
            results = json.loads(resp3)
        
            return(results)


def parse_agg_results(results):
    if not results:
        return results

    buckets = results['newestTimestamp']
    print(buckets)


    #  for computers in results['data']:
    #      hostName = computers['hostName']

    #     if 'lastSearchTime' in computers:
    #         print(hostName)
    #         print(computers['lastSearchTime'])
    #     else:
    #         print(hostName)



def main():

    results = create_spirion_session()
    parsed_results = parse_agg_results(results)


def entrypoint():
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Keyboard interrupt. Exiting.", flush=True)
        print("", flush=True)
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    entrypoint()
```

It will keep working as expected when these two functions are merged into one...,

```
def create_spirion_session():

    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

    url = 'https://SV03TMCSPAPP/WebApi/Services/Home/LogOn'
    url2 = 'https://SV03TMCSPAPP/WebApi/Services/Data/LoadEndpoints'

    headers = {
            'Accept':'application/json, text/plain',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }

    has_next_date = True
    timestampfromSpirion = "timestamp_records.csv"
    results = []
    results2 = []
    f = open('spirion.json')
    timestampData = json.load(f)

    with requests.Session() as s:

        ##authenticate first...###
        resp = s.post(url, json={"user": "","password": ""}, headers=headers, verify=False)
        print(resp.status_code)
        
        timestamp = ""
        deleteData = ""
        fields = ""

        while True:

            resp2 = s.post(url2, json={"deleteData": deleteData, "timestamp": timestamp, "fields": fields}, headers=headers, verify=False)
            resp3 = resp2.text.split('\n', 1)[1]
            results = json.loads(resp3)
        
            buckets = results['newestTimestamp']
            print(buckets)
```

Comment: You have a `return` inside of your `while` loop.  It will always return out of the function on the first iteration.

Comment: so how does it know to return results variable?